# What license applies to XWiki external repositories?

Tags: xwiki

From what I can tell XWiki licensing is LGPL:

http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/License

Just wondering what license applies to the external dependencies that Xwiki has:

http://maven.xwiki.org/externals/org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are external **dependencies**, meaning that they're separate projects that aren't yet published in the central maven repository. Each one has its own license, which is not imposed by XWiki, but they're all supposed to be LGPL-compatible.

The best thing to do is to search for the group name of the jar that you're interested in, and you'll end up on that project's homepage, where usually you'll find its license.